# Decrypting SSL traffic with Fiddler is failing

Tags: ssl, fiddler

I have Fiddler configured to decrypt SSL traffic from a Java application.

But I am seeing the following error in the Fiddler log:

```
19:39:27:1726 Fiddler.CertMaker> [C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\MakeCert.exe -pe -ss my -n "CN=test.example.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky exchange -in DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot -is my -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -cy end -a sha1 -m 132 -b 03/26/2013] Returned Error: Creation of the interception certificate failed.
makecert.exe returned -1.
Results from C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\MakeCert.exe -pe -ss my -n "CN=test.example.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky exchange -in DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot -is my -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -cy end -a sha1 -m 132 -b 03/26/2013
Error: Fail to acquire a security provider from the issuer's certificate
Failed
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using windows 8 by chance?

Answer (score 1):

This likely means that you have a 3rd party encryption provider installed (e.g. Entrust or some VPN software) that is preventing MakeCert from generating the End-Entity certificate from the FiddlerRoot certificate.

There are some ways to workaround that, but the simplest is to try using http://fiddler2.com/r/?FiddlerCertMaker instead, as it doesn't rely on `makecert.exe`.